# why do postgresql add 000 after Comma

Tags: sql, postgresql

When I use these selections I have zeros after comma, how can I get the result I expect

```
select concat(5678.0/1000,'');

select (5678.0/1000)::text;
```

both gives : ***5.6780000000000000***

what i need is this : ***5.678***

Comment: Try to use `ROUND`

Comment: Format the number using `TO_CHAR(number, pattern)`.

Comment: can u give me an example that would remove all 0 after comma @TheImpaler

Comment: i need to convert the resultat to a string without having the 0 after comma

Comment: `select to_char(5678.0/1000, 'FM999.999'); 5.678`. From [Data formatting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TRIM(TRAILING FROM <string>, <chars>)`. For example:

```
select trim(trailing from ('' || 1560.0 / 1000.0), '0'); -- 1.56

select trim(trailing from ('' || 5678.0 / 1000.0), '0'); -- 5.678
```

Answer (score 2):

`rtrim` the unwanted trailing decimal positions. A check is needed if the number has decimal point so that you do not eliminate relevant zeroes (as in `1000`)

```
with dt as (
select (5678.0/1000)::text num union all
select (5678.901/1000)::text union all
select (1000)::text
  )
select 
  num,
  case when num like '%.%' then rtrim(num,'0') else num end num2
from dt

num                 num2
5.6780000000000000  5.678
5.6789010000000000  5.678901
1000                1000
```

Comment: `RTRIM()` is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

kindly run this:

```
SELECT ROUND(5678.0/1000, 3);
```

Comment: i have diffrents numbers not always 3 numbers after commas

Comment: @DEV then you need to ask a better question